# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0, but Angular version 14.3.0 was found instead

Tags: node.js, migration, angular-cli, angular13, angular14upgrade

i was trying to upgrade the angular version from 13 to 14  i gave the command of ng update @angular/cli@14 @angular/core@14 the migration got completed but when trying to start the application facing the below mentioned error.

This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0, but Angular version 14.3.0 was found instead.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIp6e.png)

tried ng update @angular/cli@14 @angular/core@14 --allow-dirty --force
version of the node.js - 16.13.0
rxjs -6.5.5 typescript -4.6.4,
checked all the angular dependencies in package.json files after the migration completed it all got migrated from 13 to 14  but still while the start of application facing the error